# Secure login sails.js bcrypt

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, bcrypt

I'm setting up a sails.js project and I am a bit concerned about my login method and its security.

I hacked it together from research and my own code, so want to make sure it is secure.

Basically, I compare the password that is sent through with the Bcrypt hash, if they don't match we show an error and if they do we authenticate the user by setting a session ID for the user.

So specifically, is this code secure?

Secondly, I believe this code could definitely be optimized especially where I call the external functions to trigger success or error messages. How would you go about doing this?

```
    login: function (req, res) {

    // See `api/responses/login.js`
    User.findOne({
        email: req.param('email')
    }).exec(function (err, user){
        if (err) {
            return res.serverError(err);
        }
        if (!user || !req.param('password')) {
            sails.log.debug('Password or email is missing.');
        }  else {
        bcrypt.compare(req.param('password'), user.password, function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                return res.serverError(err);
            } if(!res){
                sails.log.debug('password is incorrect!!!!');
                passwordIncorrect(user);
            }if(res){
                sails.log.debug('password is correct!!!!!');
                passwordCorrect(user);

            }
        });
    }

    });

    function passwordCorrect(user){
        //Set session for user
        req.session.me = user.id;

        if (req.wantsJSON || !inputs.successRedirect) {
            return res.ok('Logged in successfully!');
        }
        return res.redirect(inputs.successRedirect);
    }

    function passwordIncorrect(user){
        if (req.wantsJSON || !inputs.invalidRedirect) {
            return res.badRequest('Invalid username/password combination.');
        }
        return res.redirect(inputs.invalidRedirect);
    }
},
```

Comment: Why are you serving non-JSON if `wantsJSON`?

Comment: I haven't implemented proper JSON responses yet, just want to make sure the current code is secure.